# pdfbox - document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, self-signed

I am using **pdfbox-1.8.8** to do the signing function on PDF file.

When I signed a document, I got

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public void signDetached(String inputFilePath, String outputFilePath, String signatureImagePath, Sign signProperties) {
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    PDDocument document = null;
    InputStream signImageStream = null;

    try {
        setTsaClient(null);
        document = PDDocument.load(inputFilePath);
        // create signature dictionary
        PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
        signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
        signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        signature.setName("VANDUC1102");
        signature.setLocation(null);
        String displayName = "Hello World, Document signed by VANDUC1102";
        String reason = reasonText+ " " + displayName;
        signature.setReason(reason);

        // the signing date, needed for valid signature
        signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());            
        int signatureInPage = signProperties.getPageNumber() + 1;
        signImageStream = new FileInputStream(new File(signatureImagePath));
        PDVisibleSignDesigner visibleSig = new PDVisibleSignDesigner(inputFilePath, signImageStream, signatureInPage);

        float xAxis = convertPixel2Point(signProperties.getX()) ;
        float yAxis = convertPixel2Point(signProperties.getY());               
        float signImageHeight = convertPixel2Point(signImageHeight);    
        float signImageWidth = convertPixel2Point(signImageWidth);

        visibleSig.xAxis(xAxis)
                .yAxis(yAxis)
                .zoom(0)
                .signatureFieldName("Signature")
                .height(signImageHeight)
                .width(signImageWidth);
        PDVisibleSigProperties signatureProperties = new PDVisibleSigProperties();

        signatureProperties.signerName(eiUser.getName())
                 .signerLocation(null)
                 .signatureReason(reason)
                 .preferredSize(0)
                 .page(signProperties.getPageNumber())
                 .visualSignEnabled(true)
                 .setPdVisibleSignature(visibleSig)
                 .buildSignature();
         // register signature dictionary and sign interface
        SignatureOptions signatureOptions = new SignatureOptions();
        signatureOptions.setVisualSignature(signatureProperties);
        signatureOptions.setPage(signatureInPage);
        document.addSignature(signature, this, signatureOptions);

        File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath);
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
        IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
        document.saveIncremental(inputStream, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (COSVisitorException | SignatureException | IOException ex) {
        log.error("signDetached ", ex);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeStream(outputStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(signImageStream);
        IOUtils.closeStream(document);
    }
}
private float convertPixel2Point(float pixel){
    return pixel * (float) 72/96;
}
```

So, I this problem because of I used **self-sign certificate** or something wrong with my code.

Here is the link of [sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwLd99D2Ui9VQjhuQTNXRzQ5bkk/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample signed PDF to inspect.

Comment: Does the problem still occur with 1.8.10 or 2.0 RC2? With the example code? I could test myself, but I'd also need the unsigned PDF.

Comment: I realize I don't need the unsigned PDF at all, I can create that one from the signed file. I just tested with the normal example and it works fine (in 2.0 RC2).

Comment: Yes. I tested version 2.0RC2 . It worked, thanks @TilmanHauserr

Answer (score 4):

### Analysis of the corrupt, signed PDF

I just had a look at your sample PDF. Structurally it looks ok, merely the data hash value given in the signature

```
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

does not match the actual hash value of the signed byte ranges

```
4f48eab20d340957bd5693104af097ed7363bd84181a6a1c834c138c1376cbe3
```

Thus, either indeed the document has been manipulated after the fact or the hash calculation in the course of the signing process already did something wrong.

As your sample code is not self-contained - it seems to rely on being part of a class supplying additional methods and implementing certain interfaces - I cannot check which one it is.

### The cause

After the OP indicated in a comment that the example he built his code upon is [CreateVisibleSignature.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.8.8/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java), I could reproduce the issue (cf. [SignLikeVanduc1102](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/sign/SignLikeVanduc1102.java#L72) test method `testCorruptOriginal`), and comparing his code to the original, the cause quickly became apparent: He uses the wrong `InputStream` parameter for his `PDDocument.saveIncremental(InputStream, OutputStream)` call:

```
File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath);
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
document.saveIncremental(inputStream, outputStream);
```

The `inputStream`

- already been read in the course of the preceding `IOUtils.copyStream` call and
- is the wrong one after all: It only refers to the original PDF but `saveIncremental` requires an `InputStream` referring to the PDF with the original PDF **plus the new, signature carrying revision**.

Thus, this can be fixed like this:

```
File outputFile = new File(outputFilePath);
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFilePath);
IOUtils.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
IOUtils.closeStream(inputStream);
inputStream = new FileInputStream(outputFile);
document.saveIncremental(inputStream, outputStream);
```

(See also [SignLikeVanduc1102](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/sign/SignLikeVanduc1102.java#L72) test method `testCorruptFixed`.)

This corresponds to the original PDFBox sample code:

```
File outputDocument = new File(document.getParent(), substring + "_signed.pdf");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(document);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputDocument);

int c;
while ((c = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  fos.write(buffer, 0, c);
}
fis.close();
fis = new FileInputStream(outputDocument);
```

The OP states that using PDFBox 2.0 his code works. This most likely is due to the fact that the incremental saving call has changed, it does not have the `inputStream` parameter anymore.

Comment: Thanks @mkl , I am new to PDF file structure, Can you give me documents to learn about PDF file structure, the way signatory of PDF file work or more detail about the way you check my file.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) and the documents referenced from there.

Comment: @mkl the code I used to sign is followed the [example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/) of PDFBox

Comment: @mkl , I used version 2.0 RC2, and It worked, thanks you

Comment: While that is good indeed, it does not explain the earlier problem. There is no obvious reason why 1.8.8 should calculate an incorrect hash value.

Comment: @vanduc1102 I could not clearly identify which of the PDFBox example classes is the base class for your tests. But apparently your link points towards the example *trunk* versions which is heading towards 2.0.0. If you actually used them in your initial attempts with PDFBox 1.8.8, it is not too surprising that something went wrong... the API in 2.0.0-RC2 is considerably different from the 1.x APIs, even from the 1.8.x APIs.

Comment: @mkl sorry, Here is example i used [example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/tags/1.8.8/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/CreateVisibleSignature.java)

Comment: @vanduc1102 Ok, comparing your code to the original example, the cause became apparent.